# React Native StackActions Pop with Parameter/Update State of Previous Screen

Tags: react-native

I have a fairly simple issue but cannot seem to find a solution for it. I have two screens that are inside a Stack Navigator. Screen A has a list with multiple items. The user can select an item for which I navigate to Screen B.

**Screen A**

```
const handleSelectItem = (customer) => {
    // Redirect to customer's page
    navigation.navigate(routes.CUSTOMER, customer);
};
```

In Screen B, the user can edit the customer and on form submission, I want to pass the object back to Screen A. Screen A is where I want to set the state after submission.

**Screen B**

```
const handleSubmit = async (form, { resetForm }) => {
    const popAction = StackActions.pop(1);
    navigation.dispatch(popAction);
};
```

How can I pass the customer back to screen A? Or how could I update Screen A's state with the edited customer?

I would prefer to avoid Redux or a solution that involves a local database.

Comment: You can try this approach from the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen

Comment: Hm interesting! So this solution simply navigates back to the previous screen instead of popping it from the stack. Is React smart enough to internally pop it from the stack or will it be place on top of the stack? E.g stack: Screen A | Screen B -> Screen A vs Screen A | Screen B -> Screen A | Screen B | Screen A

Comment: Yes if you call navigate if will go to the screen if its already there or push the screen, thats how navigation works